# JBoss and RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I need to redirect all requests that don't come from this domain **ti-passis.rhcloud.com** 
and use https to http to avoid certificate error.
Example:
https://ti-passis.rhcloud.com/contato (should'n be redirected)
https://tetraimoveis.com/contato (should be redirected because of certificate error, once the certificate is for "*.rhcloud.com")

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ti-passis.rhcloud.com$ [RC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* http:// %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The RewriteCond works alone, but if I put then together, nothing works.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is (though you likely figured it out by now)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ti-passis.rhcloud.com$ [RC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* http:// %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

You're basically just "Or"ing the expression.  As per JBoss "'ornext|OR' (or next condition)
Use this to combine rule conditions with a local OR instead of the implicit AND."